# How do i update UserControl textblock text from mainpage.xaml

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have textblock inside usercontrol.Now i want to update the text of textblock when i enter the text in mainpage.xaml.Please help

i tried this example but it does not update text.

**UserControl.xaml**

```
<TextBlock 
    x:Name="txtCartcount" 
    Text="{Binding CartCount}"      
    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    FontWeight="Bold" 
    FontSize="15" 
    Foreground="#E4328A"   
    HorizontalAlignment="Center">
</TextBlock>
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
private string _CartCount;

public string CartCount
{
    get { return _CartCount; }
    set { _CartCount = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("CartCount"); }
}

CartCount=txtMessage.text;
```

Comment: I think you can only bind controls in your codebehind wich belongs to your xaml page. Instead you can use static property to pass the value to your UserControl page.Set the value in a static property (App.Myproperty=mytext) and get it from the UserControl page (txtcartCount.text=App.mytext)

Comment: Hi paul,I used this code in mainpage constructor(){ IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["State"] = totalQty;
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();} and showing totalQty in usercontrol textblock page like var item = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["State"];
               txtCartcount.Text =Convert.ToString(item); in mainpage.xaml i have button.if i have click button totalQty will update in usercontrol textblock.how can i redirect to usercontrol from button click event

Comment: If I m not misunderstanding..;you want to navigate to Usercontrol page when you click on the Update button ...is that correct ? NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("UserControl.xaml",UriKind.Relative));

Comment: Im wondering why you use IsolatedSorageSettings to pass the value...Do you really need to store this value even when the app  is turned off ?

Comment: No.if i have use NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("UserControl.xaml",UriKind.Relative));in update button i am getting design issue

Comment: I dont't get it... you should be able to use NavigationService.navigate on event Button, no error should raise ...Can you tell me more about the issue you got ?

Answer (score 1):

I'll suppose your user control contains other elements and not just the `TextBox`, if it's not the case, you can put your `TextBox` directly into your `MainPage.xaml` as it's easier.

Given that assumption, you have two options to change the text insideyour `UserControl`:

- **Without Binding**: You should publicly expose a setter of your `TextBox.Text` property inside your `UserControl` so that you can modify it from your `MainPage` like this

> myUserControl.SetText("MyText");

- **With binding**: You should define a dependency property inside your user control that will wrap your `TextBox.Text` property. Then in the xaml of your main page you can bind this new defined property of your `UserControl` as if it was a `TextBlock`. Here's how you'd do this:

In your `UserControl`'s codebehind:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Text", typeof(String),typeof(UserControl), null
    );

//This dependency property defined above will wrap the TextBlock's Text property
public String Text
{
    get { return (String)GetValue(txtCartcount.Text); }
    set { SetValue(txtCartcount.Text, value); }
}
```

Now your UserControl have a Bindable `Text` property that you can use in your `MainPage.xaml` like this:

```
<UserControl
    Text = "{Binding PropertyToBindTo}"
</UserControl>
```

So now if you set up your binding correctly, when you change the bound property and fire up the `NotifyChanged` event, the defined `Text` property of your `UserControl` will get the notification and will call its setter, which will set the real `Text` property of your `txtCartcount`.

Hope this helps.